# Firestore Error - Cannot read property `firestore` of null

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use firestore with my react project after authentication to write some data to firebase. But whenever `doc.set` is called, I get an error saying `Cannot read property firestore of null`.

Here is my firebase config file.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  console.log('Initializing firebase');
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

export default firebase;
```

And here is my firebase utils file which I use to access the common requirements from firebase.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

import {FIREBASE_COLLECTIONS} from './constants';

export const getIdToken = async () => {
  try {
    const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
    if (currentUser) {
      const idToken = await currentUser.getIdToken();
      return idToken;
    }
    return currentUser;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error || new Error('Error retrieving ID token');
  }
};

export const logout = async () => {
  try {
    await firebase.auth().signOut();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error || new Error('Error logging out');
  }
};

export const loginUser = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  try {
    const user = await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    let message = '';
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'auth/invalid-email':
        message = 'Invalid Email Id';
        break;
      case 'auth/user-disabled':
        message = 'User is temporarily disabled';
        break;
      case 'auth/user-not-found':
        message = 'User not found. Please register';
        break;
      case 'auth/wrong-password':
        message = 'Incorrect password';
        break;
      default:
        message = 'Error logging in';
        break;
    }
    throw new Error(message);
  }
};

export const registerUser = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  try {
    const user = await firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    let message = '';
    switch (errorCode) {
      case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
        message = 'Email already in use';
        break;
      case 'auth/invalid-email':
        message = 'Invalid email ID';
        break;
      case 'auth/weak-password':
        message = 'Weak password';
        break;
      default:
        message = 'Error registering user';
        break;
    }
    throw new Error(message);
  }
};

export const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.setCustomParameters({prompt: 'select_account'});
  const scopes = ['profile', 'email'];
  scopes.forEach(scope => provider.addScope(scope));
  try {
    return await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
  } catch (error) {
    let message = '';
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential':
        message = 'Account exists with another sign in type';
        break;
      case 'auth/popup-closed-by-user':
        message = 'Login popup closed';
        break;
      default:
        message = 'Error signing in';
        break;
    }
    throw new Error(message);
  }
};

export const isLoggedIn = (): boolean => {
  const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
  return currentUser !== null;
};

export const getUserDoc = (
  id: string
): firebase.firestore.DocumentReference => {
  return firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection(FIREBASE_COLLECTIONS.USERS)
    .doc(id);
};

export default firebase;
```

I'm calling the getUserDoc function from the firebase utils and using it to write data to the user.

```
function* registerWithPassword(user: UserInput) {
  try {
    const userData: firebase.auth.UserCredential = yield call(
      registerUser,
      user.email,
      user.password
    );
    if (userData === null || userData.user === null) {
      yield put(
        authFailureAction.failure({
          register: 'Unable to register user',
        })
      );
    } else {
      const userDoc = getUserDoc(userData.user.uid);   
      yield call(
        userDoc.set,
        {labels: [], pinnedNotes: [], name: user.name},
        {merge: true}
      );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log({e});
    yield put(
      authFailureAction.failure({
        register: e.message || 'Unable to register user',
      })
    );
  }
}
```

When `userDoc.set` is called, the error occurs.
From some debugging, it looks like firebase is null. That's why `firebase.firestore()` throws an error.
But if firebase is null, auth shouldn't work too but I haven't had any problems with firebase auth.

Also note that I am importing `firebaseConfig.js` in my `index.js` file, so I'm sure that firebase has been initialized. This is also due to the fact that users are being registered but for some reason when I'm accessing `firestore` from `firebase.firestore()`, `firebase` is null.

You can access the project [here](https://github.com/sriramr98/Google-Keep-Clone/tree/feature/add-note). Try to register a user and you'll see the error. Since it depends on Firebase, you'll have to add a relevant `.env` file.

Comment: I have some doubts about this import syntax:

`import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';`

Haven't been able to reproduce so far but is it possible that you're only importing the auth module correctly?

Comment: No man. I am importing `firebase/firestore`. When auth works, firebase shouldn't be null when I'm trying to use firestore.

Answer (score 2):

The error may be occurring because of the issue with the multiple firebase imports/exports done in files instead of a single module as a source.

The `firebase` module could be exported only in `firebase_config` file, and then be imported from there in other files.

So in `firebase_utils`, you can add instead of:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

`import firebase from './firebase-config.js';`

You can also remove `export default firebase;` from `firebase_utils` to prevent `firebase` namespace from getting overwritten.

So the final `firebase_config.js` file may look as:

```js
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK)
var firebase = require("firebase/app");

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");

// Your app's Firebase project configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Single source for all imports of the firebase module
export default firebase;
```

You can also take reference from [this article](https://css-tricks.com/intro-firebase-react/#article-header-id-8) and [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/risan/react-firebase-auth-example/blob/master/src/components/app.js) for `firebase` importing examples.

Comment: Tried it, man. It doesn't work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to comment on what might be happening from the above mentioned details. Would it be possible for you to post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the same?

Comment: Added project link in the question. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the firebase that has been initialized.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'; <-- This one hasn't been initialized.
...
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase; <-- This one is initialized.
```

In your firebase_config, add firestore, and auth

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';      <----- add this here.
import 'firebase/firestore'; <----- add this here.

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  console.log('Initializing firebase');
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

export default firebase;
```

Change the first 3 lines.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

import {FIREBASE_COLLECTIONS} from './constants';

export const getIdToken = async () => {
  try {
    const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
    if (currentUser) {
      const idToken = await currentUser.getIdToken();
....
```

to

```
import firebase from './firebase_config.js'; // or wherever your firebase.initializeApp(...) live.

import {FIREBASE_COLLECTIONS} from './constants';

export const getIdToken = async () => {
  try {
    const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
    if (currentUser) {
      const idToken = await currentUser.getIdToken();
....
```

Good day.

Comment: Doesn't work man. Tried this too. I moved on from the firebase_config method because it didn't work. So I thought a separate import will work.

Comment: @Doppio downvoted by accident. I think this is the cause of the problem. Every firebase sub-module has to be imported before initialization and just once. Please make an edit to take downvote back.

Comment: @ChristosLytras what do you mean by take downvote back? Is that a thing? O.O

Comment: @Doppio of course you can take downvote back and upvote after an edit and it's very logical if you think about it, because after an edit a wrong answer can be a correct answer. Just make a small edit in the code.

Comment: There you got a +1. I could have edited myself, but I don't like to do it that way. Check this meta post about it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260017/why-am-i-allowed-to-take-back-my-upvote